# Maximum value in a row where the data is a string containing an integer

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

What I am trying to do is get the maximum from a row containing data which is of the form "x kg" where x is an integer but overall this forms a string. The issue is that running a `=MAX(C5:AA5)` over this returns 0 (for obvious reasons).

I thought about using another formula `=LEFT(C5, LEN(C5) - 3)` but the issue with this is that it only works for a single cell.

How can I (using a script if necessary), get the maximum value in the row knowing the row is only strings with integers in string format in them?

My rows look something like this: (note that commas represent another cell)

`"20 kg", "30 kg", "40 kg", "50 kg", ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shorter solution:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A20:A, " kg", ""))))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 2):

You could create a custom number format instead of adding the text "kg".  Select Format > Number > More Formats > Custom Number Formats > and enter 0 "kg" in the text field.  Now that format will be saved for you, you can apply it to your whole row and get the `MAX()` formula working correctly for you while keeping your visual format.

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(IFERROR(VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A20:A, "\d+")))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I have to wait 6 minutes but I will accept this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

even shorter:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(IFERROR(SPLIT(A20:A," "))))
```

[image: 0]